# NodeJs run with Visual Studio Code Issue

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

how to solve this issue? trying to debug a NodeJs Code in Visual studio code..
${workspaceFolder} can not be resolved. Please open a folder

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do what it says--open a folder. Just create a folder and make a file inside it. Then, you'll be able to debug.